# What does N-day correlation mean?

Tags: time-series, correlation, cross-section

I have a stock price data for each day for stocks A and B for 5 years. I am asked to calculate: 1-week, 1-month, 3-month and the 1-year correlation between them.

I am puzzled as to the definition. Do I need to consider prices with the gap of 1-week (for example) to calculate 1-week correlation and similarly for others? But this means there are several ways I can start from the first day, the second day, so on...

Can someone clarify this, please?